# I want to classify Images with small dataset using tensorflow without CUDA install Windows

Tags: windows, image, tensorflow, classification

I have to do a vihecle Image classification , my data is about 5000 images cause its to learn how to classify .. anyway the problem is jupyter gives me an error when try to use tensorflow and that error means I have to install CUDA .. I dont want to install CUDA .. can my project done otherway?

Comment: You can install a version of tensorflow that does not require CUDA or a GPU.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539786/does-tensorflow-need-gpu)

Comment: thank you very much it has been solved

Answer (score 0):

thank all I found the solution
its by using the CPU
jupyeter training now !!
am soooo happy for the first classify
to people who have the same problem and want to know what to do
just type those lines before import tensorflow
( import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf )
thanks !